# Setting up a PHP decent development environment

Tags: php, git, docker, bitbucket

After years of spaghetti code (I'm Italian, I do really know what spaghetti are) I'm trying to set up a decent php development environment.

This is my battleplan:

1. install git and docker on my laptop;
2. create a docker virtual enviroment as much similar as possible to
   the production LAMP (shared) server;
3. use sshfs to mount the docker VE web server root directory on my laptop;
4. on the laptop, init a git repository inside the mount point;
5. use my favourite ide (aptana studio) to create a php project in the mount point directory;
6. test the code pointing a browser to docker VE ip;
7. set up a bitbucket account to automatically deploy git commits on production server.

What do you think about? Any chance it could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the official php language docker image:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/

This enables you to create an image that packages your php code, rather than having to map volumes at run-time.

## Example 1 (with Dockerfile)

```
├── build_and_run.sh
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    └── index.php
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

### build_and_run.sh

Script that builds a new container image and launches it:

```
docker build -t my-php-app .
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-php-app
```

Apache is configured to listen on port 8080

## Example 2 (without Dockerfile)

The php image can also be run without a docker file. Just provide a mapping to the source code locally:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-apache-php-app -v "$(pwd)/src":/var/www/html -p 8080:80 php:5.6-apache
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But it is not clear to me how can I edit the official php image to replicate the configuration of production server... Shall I install/unistall modules from within the dockerfile? Same for php.ini editing?

Another question, if you don't mind: what about the db server? Would you put it into the doker image or leave it on a separate environment?

Many thank, again!

Comment: @user1662618 The image documentation explains how additional modules can be added. If you want to replicate another machine, then I suppose you could build your own image. Finally for simplicity I'd run the database in a different container and link them together. Again I'd use standard containers, to make life simpler.